# How to measure correlation in polynomial regression?

Tags: regression, correlation, polynomial, quadratic-form

I have two variables that have a quadratic relationship. I can fit such an equation and get the R-squared, but how can I measure the degree to which the two variables are associated? Does a correlation coefficient makes sense in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: What does $R^2$ not give you that you need?

Comment: Correlation coefficient may or may not tell you much.  E.g. with $y=x^2$ and $x\sim Unif(-1,1)$ you get correlation 0.  There are other measures of association, e.g. mutual information (see Murphy "Machine learning" 2.8.3).  But what do you want to use this for?

Comment: One standard solution is the correlation coefficient between the predicted and actual values.  This is directly related to $R^2.$  Whether either makes sense depends on your reply to the question by @Ott.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful answers. The only reason I wanted to measure a correlation coefficient is because I am working on a project, the plan of which assumed we would be finding a linear relationship between variables and thus measure a correlation coefficient. This ended up being quadratic and I was not keen in using the correlation coefficient as we typically know it (Pearson's or Spearman's). Since R-squared is a metric applicable for any relationship I will go with that, and also explore the other suggestions.